# How can I make sure that money goes to the right player?

Tags: roblox

I created a tycoon game in Roblox and made it so every 10 seconds (the Val.value means how much money you have), and you begin getting the money as soon as you claim the tycoon. My Problem now is that, for some reason, when you play it in multiplayer, **it gives money to other players but not to the player who's owner of the tycoon**.Please Help. Anyways here's the code:

```
CurrencyName = "Money" --Change "Cash" to whatever the name of your currency will be.
StarterValue = 0

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr)
    local fold = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
    fold.Name = "leaderstats" 
    val = Instance.new("IntValue", fold)
    val.Name = CurrencyName
    val.Value = StarterValue
end)


v = script.Parent.Values.OwnerValue
m1 = game.ReplicatedStorage.Mosques.Mosque1
b = script.Parent.b

PayOut = 2
WaitBetweenPayout = 10

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(Hit)

    if Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and v.Value == nil then

        local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)

        v.Value = Player

        script.Parent.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.CanCollide = false
        script.Parent.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = tostring(v.Value).."'s Mosque"
        
        local Repeat = true  --Repeat giving currrency



        while true do
            wait()
            if Repeat ==  true then
                wait(WaitBetweenPayout)
                val.Value = val.Value+PayOut 
            end
        end
        
        b.a.Touched:connect(function(Hit)
            if Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
                if v.Value == Player and val.Value >= 10 then
                    m1.Mosq.Decorations.Outside.Stairs:Clone()
                    m1.Mosq.Decorations.Outside.Stairs.Parent = workspace.Mosques.mosque1
                    b.a:Destroy()
                    val.Value = val.Value - 10
                    PayOut = PayOut + 2
                    b.b.CanCollide = true
                    b.b.CanTouch = true
                    b.b.Transparency = 0
                    b.b.BillboardGui.Enabled = true
                end
            end
        end)

        b.b.Touched:connect(function(Hit)
            if Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
                if v.Value == Player and val.Value >= 25 then
                    m1.Mosq.Decorations.Outside.Sign:Clone()
                    m1.Mosq.Decorations.Outside.Sign.Parent = workspace.Mosques.mosque1
                    b.b:Destroy()
                    val.Value = val.Value - 25
                    PayOut = PayOut + 4
                    b.c.CanCollide = true
                    b.c.CanTouch = true
                    b.c.Transparency = 0
                    b.c.BillboardGui.Enabled = true
                end
            end
        end)
        
        b.c.Touched:connect(function(Hit)
            if Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
                if v.Value == Player and val.Value >= 45 then
                    m1.Mosq.WallsEtc.Roofnfloor.FloorF:Clone()
                    m1.Mosq.WallsEtc.Roofnfloor.FloorF.Parent = workspace.Mosques.mosque1
                    b.c:Destroy()
                    val.Value = val.Value - 45
                    PayOut = PayOut + 4
                    b.d.CanCollide = true
                    b.d.CanTouch = true
                    b.d.Transparency = 0
                    b.d.BillboardGui.Enabled = true
        b.d.Touched:connect(function(Hit)
            if Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
                if v.Value == Player and val.Value >= 25 then
                    m1.Mosq.WallsEtc.WallParts.WallPart1:Clone()
                    m1.Mosq.WallsEtc.WallParts.WallPart1.Parent = workspace.Mosques.mosque1
                    b.d:Destroy()
                    val.Value = val.Value - 25
                    PayOut = PayOut + 2
                    b.e.CanCollide = true
                    b.e.CanTouch = true
                    b.e.Transparency = 0
                    b.e.BillboardGui.Enabled = true 
                    end
                end
            end)
    b.e.Touched:connect(function(Hit)
            if Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
                if v.Value == Player and val.Value >= 25 then
                    m1.Mosq.WallsEtc.WallParts.WallPart2:Clone()
                    m1.Mosq.WallsEtc.WallParts.WallPart2.Parent = workspace.Mosques.mosque1
                    b.e:Destroy()
                    val.Value = val.Value - 25
                    PayOut = PayOut + 2
                    b.f.CanCollide = true
                    b.f.CanTouch = true
                    b.f.Transparency = 0
                    b.f.BillboardGui.Enabled = true 
                end
            end
        end)        
    b.f.Touched:connect(function(Hit)
            if Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
                if v.Value == Player and val.Value >= 125 then
                    m1.Mosq.WallsEtc.Walls.EtcRoom.Wall1:Clone()
                    m1.Mosq.WallsEtc.Walls.EtcRoom.Wall1.Parent = workspace.Mosques.mosque1
                    b.f:Destroy()
                    val.Value = val.Value - 125
                    PayOut = PayOut + 6
                    
                end
            end
        end)

        
                end
            end
         end)
        end
    end)
```

Comment: By the way, your code would be a lot easier to reason about if you would be using comments to say which part of the code is resposible for which aspect of your game mechanics. It's also not a good idea to use one-character variable names, because it is easy to forget what they mean. To improve code readability, a variable should be named after what it represents. For example, when `v` represents the owning player, then I would name it something like `owner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this code here:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr)
    local fold = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
    fold.Name = "leaderstats" 
    val = Instance.new("IntValue", fold)
    val.Name = CurrencyName
    val.Value = StarterValue
end)
```

sets up a new IntValue representing the money balance for each player it connects to. But it then assigns this to the variable `val`, which is then shared by all players. That means that `val` always refers to the balance of the last player who connected. Which is why later, when you do `val.Value = val.Value+PayOut`, the money doesn't go to the "tycoon" but to another player.

So how do you solve this problem?

First of all, I would rename the variable `val` to something that's more descriptive. Like `tycoonPlayerMoney`. That way this line in the PlayerAdded:connect handler would already look really fishy at first glance:

```
tycoonPlayerMoney = Instance.new("IntValue", fold)
```

I mean why would you change the value that represents the money of the tycoon player with something new every time a new player connects? Does that make sense here? No, it doesn't! See? Proper variable naming makes logical mistakes like that far easier to spot. The variable that temporarily holds the newly created money value for the new player should probably be a variable that is `local` to this function.

Then you need to make sure that `tycoonPlayerMoney` actually points to the money IntValue of the player who is currently "the tycoon". Unfortunately your code doesn't seem to include the part that makes the player "the tycoon" (or if it does, I can't find it due to lack of comments in the code). That code would need to store the personal money value of "the tycoon" in this variable, so you can use it to give money specifically to "the tycoon" later via `tycoonPlayerMoney.Value = tycoonPlayerMoney.Value + PayOut`.

---

Oh, and it also appears that you create a "leaderstats" folder that's parented to each player when they connect. That means that each player has a separate leaderstats folder which doesn't automatically get synced with those of the others. Are you sure you don't want the leadership stats in `ReplicatedStorage` instead so that you have only one global leaderboard that's automatically synced between all players? Or perhaps I am just misunderstanding what "leaderstats" actually means and it is indeed private data specific to each player.

Comment: i thought i fixed the problem by remvoing the game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr) and also changing local fold = Instance.new("Folder", plr) into local fold = Instance.new("Folder", player)
 but now that works How do i buy something because just using : if  val.Value >= 10 doesn't work. please answer

Comment: @animatopiaanimations If you have a new question, please post a new question. But you would be well-advised to first think about the problem yourself for a few hours. You might find the reason for your problem yourself if you properly analyze and debug your code and look at any potential error messages. And as I just demonstrated, just renaming variables to what they actually mean can already help you to spot some obvious bugs.